# Provide default value if command returns with non-zero exit code

Tags: bash, shell, cat, exit-status

I have some configuration in file `config` and would like to `cat` that file. However, sometimes `config` doesn't exist. In this case, I would like to have my command output a default value.

Perhaps something that worked like this:

```
$ ls
$ cat config || echo 42
42
$ echo 73 > config
$ cat config || echo 42
73
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your construct is fine. You could even do someting like

```
cat config || cat defaultconfig
```

If you use some random command (like the `./get_config_from_web` in comments), you'll have to make sure the command does give a sensible return status. That can be tricky, shell scripts just return the result of the last command executed, you'd have to do a `exit` if you want something else as result.

Comment: Presuming of course that `defaultconfig` is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: The critical problem here is that it's the output of the commands that I care about. `cat config` gives an error `cat: config: No such file or directory` if `config` doesn't exist. So I end up getting the output of both commands instead of just the second one.

Comment: Ah! I could pipe stderr to `/dev/null` and it works: `cat config 2> /dev/null || echo 42`.

Answer (score 2):

The following will echo 42 for any noncaught error condition:

```
trap "echo 42" ERR
```

You can make this a configurable variable:

```
trap 'echo "${CONFIG:=42}"' ERR  # if $CONFIG is not set, it will be defaulted to 42
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand how the `trap` logic would be combined with the `cat config` command from the example. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `$cat config` -> "cat: config: No such file or directory\n" (from cat's error) "42" (from the trap's echo)

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -a config ]; then cat config; else echo ${DEFAULT};fi
```

assuming the variable DEFAULT is set to something beforehand.

Comment: This appears to work for the `cat config` example, but I was hoping for a solution that works regardless of whether the failure is due to a missing file. For example `./get_config_from_web.sh || echo 42`.

Comment: does it have to be a one-liner ?

Comment: Well... I could write a script that essentially does the same thing as above, but I was hoping that there was built-in `bash` syntax that supported this kind of a thing and I just hadn't learned about it yet. If no such `bash` syntax exists I guess the next best thing is a script, and the best script would be an elegant succinct one.

Comment: I personally have not seen anything other than `||` and `&&` constructs to determine the success or failure of an action in the same command space. But again with the enhancements in shell and me being an old timer, it might entirely be possible in a nook and cranny that eludes me and probably you as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use the exit code in an if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat config
if [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
    echo "VALUE"
fi
```

If the previous command succeeds it will exit with a "0" value. So you are telling it that on any other exit (failures) it will output whatever is in the "VALUE".